# Why does Adam outperform SGD in logistic regression?

Tags: deep-learning, logistic-regression, optimization, gradient-descent, performance

I am training a logistic regression model. In case it matters, the features are 1376-dimensional embeddings output from a neural network. I tried both SGD and Adam with a learning rate of $10^{-3}$ for 100 epochs, and the final AUC is 0.875 for SGD and 0.973 for Adam.

Why is Ada so much better for a convex optimization problem such as logistic regression?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in their paper, Adam performs better with higher dimensional spaces.

> For all such noisy objectives, efficient stochastic optimization
> techniques are required. The focus of this paper is on the
> optimization of stochastic objectives with high-dimensional parameters
> spaces. [1]

[1] Kingma, D. P., & Ba, J. (2014). Adam: A method for stochastic optimization. arXiv preprint arXiv:1412.6980.